# SharedPreferences to save user profile

Tags: android

I'm new to SharedPreferences. I'd like to save user profile using sharedpreferences, and the second time the user goes to profile activity, he should see the details he filled in before. How am I able to do that? Can you please give me some code to do that?

Here's what I have tried but I don't know what to put inside if else statements:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class A extends Activity
{
   private static final String MY_KEY = "myprefs";
   private SharedPreferences myPrefs;
   private boolean loggedIn;

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.iprofile);

   myPrefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);

   loggedIn = myPrefs.getBoolean("loggedIn", false);  //default to false if the value has not been set

   if(loggedIn)
   {
      //do stuff

   }
  else
   {
       //do other stuff
    }
}
}
```

this is my xml file: http://pastebin.com/gXCHpk0E and my java class: http://pastebin.com/NZJ0CR8H

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here, surely if loggedIn is true, you need to read the rest of the values from the SharedPreferences object populate your activity.

If not logged in then you want to redirect your user to somewhere to log in where they can enter the required details?

Comment: SharedPreferences only saves data of primitive data types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume, that you have an user class, what looks something like this :

```
class User
{
    private String name;
    private String pass;
    private int age;

    public User(String name, String pass, int age)
    {
        this.name = name;
        ...
    }

    //getters and setters
}
```

You could create a static utility function to read or write if needed the user in the SharedPreferences of the phone:

```
public class UserCreator
{
    public static User getUser(Context context)
    {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("Name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        //Check if the user is already stored, if is, then simply get the data from
        //your SharedPreference object.

        boolean isValid = prefs.getBoolean("valid", false);

        if(isValid)
        {
            String user = prefs.getString("user", "");
            String pass = prefs.getString("pass", "");
            int age = prefs.getInt("age", 0); 
            ...
            return new User(user, pass, age); 
        }
        //If not, then store data
        else
        {
            //for example show a dialog here, where the user can log in.
            //when you have the data, then:

            if(...login successful...)
            {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putString("user", "someusername");
                editor.putString("pass", "somepassword");
                editor.putInt("age", 20);
                editor.putBoolean("valid", true);
                ...
                editor.commit();
            }

            return getUser(context);
        }
    }
}
```

If you have that, then you can simply do this in your Activity (in fact all of your activites):

```
User user = UserCreator.getUser(this);
```

If the users data is stored, then it will return a valid user object. If it is not, it will ask the user until he/she enters acceptable data, and return a valid User object after.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following snippet:

```
  SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
                prefsEditor.putString("user", edtsample.getEditableText().toString());
                prefsEditor.commit();
```

and for retrieving the same user and password:

```
 SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String prefName = myPrefs.getString("SRATE", "srate");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sharedpreferences and a text file to do that.
Save the profile's name in the text file and the rest of the data in the sharedpreference  file of that profile name.
Here is a sample code how to save it:

```
File f = new File("/data/data/<package name>/shared_prefs/"
            + profileName + ".xml");
if (f.exists()) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Profile with that name already exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
    try {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this
            .getSharedPreferences(profileName,
                        Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
        Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("phn", phone_det.getText().toString()
                .trim());
        editor.putString("message", message_det.getText()
                    .toString());
        editor.putInt("Year", yrs);
        editor.putInt("Month", mon);
        editor.putInt("Day", da);
        editor.putInt("Hour", hr);
        editor.putInt("Minute", min);
        editor.commit();
        OutputStream outstream = this.openFileOutput(
                "Profiles.txt", Context.MODE_APPEND);
        // if file the available for reading
        OutputStreamWriter outputwriter = new OutputStreamWriter(
                    outstream);
        outputwriter.write(profileName);
        outputwriter.write('\r');
        outputwriter.write('\n');
        outputwriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this,
        "Saving profile failed," + e.toString(),
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

and to open it:

```
        try {
        // open the file for reading
        InputStream instream = openFileInput(
                "Profiles.txt");
        // if file the available for reading
        InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
        BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);

        String profileName;

        // read every line of the file into the line-variable, on line at
        // the time
        while ((profileName = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
            Profile objContact = new Profile();
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity()
                    .getSharedPreferences(profileName,
                            Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
            String phnno = sharedPreferences.getString("phn", "");
            String message = sharedPreferences.getString("message", "");
            String year = String.valueOf((sharedPreferences.getInt("Year",
                    0)));
            int month = (sharedPreferences.getInt("Month", 0));
            String day = String
                    .valueOf((sharedPreferences.getInt("Day", 0)));
            String hour = String.valueOf((sharedPreferences.getInt("Hour",
                    0)));
            String minute = String.valueOf((sharedPreferences.getInt(
                    "Minute", 0)));
            objContact.setName(line);
            objContact.setMessage(message);
            objContact.setDate(DateTime);
            objContact.setPhone(phnno);
            title.add(objContact);
        }
    } catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
        // do something if the myfilename.txt does not exits
    }
```